# Spring boot maven plugin not generating executable jar

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I am developing an application ,and using spring boot with maven. I want to generate a executable jar, however the jar is not being generated in the target folder. 
I am doing mvn clean package. Here is my pom file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.XX.api</groupId>
<artifactId>demo-api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>API-Interface</name>
<description </description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

Comment: What does happen? Can you share Maven's output?

Answer (score 1):

exactly `executable` ? Have a look at Spring documentation [create a ‘fully executable’ jar with Maven](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-install)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `repackage` goal in `pom.xml` could also resolve the issue.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```